# Is there a pythonic way of incrementing values of a column based on values from another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to assign incremental values to a column. However, the increment is not continuous, the row at which the increment takes place is dependent on the value of another column.

Currently I am using a for loop for this which painstakingly slow. I am getting the result I want as shown below. Can you suggest a more pythonic way to do this?

```py
a=1
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index,'trip_id'] = a
    if df.loc[index,'interim_tour_chk'] >= 0:
        a = a+1
```

[my desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTp4K.png)

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to quite match your desired results. Is it correct that you want "trip_id" to increase by 1 every time there's a 0 in "interim_tourchk"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like only `cumsum` will not solve your problem , before doing that we need do `diff`

```
df['trip_id']=(df.interim_tourchk.diff()<0).cumsum()
df
    interim_tourchk  trip_id
0                 0        0
1                 1        0
2                 0        1
3                 1        1
4                 0        2
5                 1        2
6                 0        3
7                 0        3
8                 0        3
9                 1        3
10                0        4
11                0        4
12                0        4
13                1        4
```

Comment: This is actually what I need. This is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df['trip_id'] = (df['interim_tour_chk'] == 0).cumsum()
```

Explanation:

`(df['interim_tour_chk'] == 0)` will return a pandas series of boolean of whether each 'interim_tour_chk' is equals to 0. And here's the documentation of [pandas's cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html).

Comment: Please check wen-ben's solution

Answer (score 0):

You don't need using index though:

```
a = 1
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    row['trip_id'] = a
    if row['interim_tour_chk'] == 0:
        a += 1
```

Also mind your comparison operator is `==` not assign operator `=`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting correctly, you want the value of df.trip_id to increase by 1 each time df.interim_tourchk is 0.

This will get the job done:

```
df['trip_id'] = (df.interim_tourchk == 0).cumsum()
```

(and subtract 1 if you want it to start from 0).

Comment: You're welcome. You can hit the green check mark next to the answer that was most helpful to accept it.

Comment: I am sorry, this is not what I wanted...I checked and found that it works perfectly when the 'interim_tourchk' variable series is 01-01-01...and so on but doesnt work when the series goes 0-0-1 or 0-0-0-1 (that is because it increments the value in the trip_id column whenever it encounters a "0" in the interim_tourchk column. Wen-ben's solution is what I needed. Thank you so much!